# Xamarin Forms crashing on Xamarin.Auth library on a testing device out of three

Tags: json, xamarin.forms, authorization

Visual Studio 2015. Xamarin Forms cross platform PCL application. The code builds and runs just fine on both VS android emulator and when deployed on an android 6.0 Samsung 815T device. Same code breaks with unhandled exception when deployed on android 7.0 Samsung SM-A510F device.
I am posting here just the part of code causing the unhandled exception, but the entire (very short) sample project can be download (or just browsed) at [native authentication flow in a Xamarin.Forms application](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/OAuthNativeFlow/)

What the code is doing here is using the Xamarin.Auth library (v. 1.5.0.3) putting together a json object and passing it to (in this particular example) a Google web service in order to process it and grant user authentication through its API.

```
       var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
            clientId,
            secret,
            Constants.Scope,
            new Uri(Constants.AuthorizeUrl),
            new Uri(redirectUri),
            new Uri(Constants.AccessTokenUrl),
            null,
            true);

        authenticator.Completed += OnAuthCompleted;
        AuthenticationState.Authenticator = authenticator;

        var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
        presenter.Login(authenticator);
```

The unhandled exception occurs at above very last line.

Debug exception follows:

> 09-18 11:39:43.018 I/MonoDroid(15642): System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>   09-18 11:39:43.018 I/MonoDroid(15642):   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
>   09-18 11:39:43.018 I/MonoDroid(15642):   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].get_Item (TKey key) [0x0001e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
>   09-18 11:39:43.018 I/MonoDroid(15642):   at Android.Support.CustomTabs.Chromium.SharedUtilities.PackageManagerHelper.GetPackageNameToUseImplementation (Android.Content.Context context, System.String url) [0x0008b] in C:\cxa\source\Xamarin.Auth.LinkSource\System.Json\JsonPrimitive.cs:222 
>   09-18 11:39:43.018 I/MonoDroid(15642):   at Android.Support.CustomTabs.Chromium.SharedUtilities.CustomTabActivityHelper.LaunchUrlWithCustomTabsOrFallback (Android.App.Activity activity, Android.Support.CustomTabs.CustomTabsIntent custom_tabs_intent, Android.Net.Uri uri, Android.Support.CustomTabs.Chromium.SharedUtilities.ICustomTabFallback fallback) [0x00003] in C:\cxa\source\Xamarin.Auth.LinkSource\System.Json\JsonObject.cs:173 
>   09-18 11:39:43.018 I/MonoDroid(15642):   at Xamarin.Auth.WebAuthenticatorNativeBrowserActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00000] in C:\cxa\source\Xamarin.Auth.LinkSource\System.Json\JsonValue.cs:282 
>   09-18 11:39:43.018 I/MonoDroid(15642):   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x0000f] in <61dabd3f0b0446bc8b570d6071d995d7>:0 
>   09-18 11:39:43.018 I/MonoDroid(15642):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:f4ad715c-48ac-488e-8536-42352bd621b5 (intptr,intptr,intptr)

It seems an expected key is missing but I cannot understand which one nor why this should happen ONLY with the samsung phone testing device while it doesn't with the tablet samsung s2 or any Visual Studio android virtual emulator.